# InvalidArgumentException Action CategoriaController@destroy not defined

Tags: laravel

me da error cuando en el formulario coloco

```
{{Form::open(array('action'=>array('CategoriaController@destroy', $cat->idecategoria), 'method'=>'delete'))}}
```

me da este error

> InvalidArgumentException
> Action CategoriaController@destroy not defined. (View: C:\ProyectoVentas\sisVentas\resources\views\almacen\categoria\modal.blade.php)

Comment: Deberías agregar tu controlador y tú ruta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!